# Discord Python: How to mention a user along with sending a GIF

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been looking for a way to code my Discord bot to mention a user that was tagged by a certain command as well as sending an image/gif to go with the message. So far, I am able to generate random images from one command and mention a user with a different command. I just need to figure out how to implement both for one command.

Here is the code that I used to generate random images from one command:

```
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith("?DOG"):
    jessie1 = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/432563417887277060/484484259386621993/22B25E7A-3157-4C23-B889-47ECFE8A15A9.jpg"
    snowy = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/487045791697862666/487390822485065749/824B6151-E818-49A4-A564-C2C752ED6384.jpg"
    await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice([snowy, jessie1]))
```

Here is the code that I used to mention another user:

```
    elif message.content.upper().startswith('?GIVE BANANA'):
        user = message.mentions[0]
        responses = ["{} gave a banana to {} :banana:"]
        choice = random.choice(responses)
        choice = choice.format(message.author.mention, user.mention)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, choice)
```

Within the second code, I can't figure out how to add an image with it. Preferably, I would like to generate random images with it, which is why I provided two code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You format the message with the mention and then the link to the message.

```
 elif message.content.upper().startswith('?SEND GIF'):
        user = message.mentions[0]
        jessie1 = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/432563417887277060/484484259386621993/22B25E7A-3157-4C23-B889-47ECFE8A15A9.jpg"
        snowy = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/487045791697862666/487390822485065749/824B6151-E818-49A4-A564-C2C752ED6384.
        gif_message = "{} here is the gif {}".format(user.mention, random.choice([snowy, jessie1]))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, gif_message)
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed some things and finally got what I wanted. Within the parenthesis after format, I added "message.author.mention" before the "user.mention" so that I can mention myself as well as the user I mentioned in my command :)